# Unwanted VB.Net 2013 Form Resizing and Restoring

Tags: vb.net, forms, resize, restore

I recently upgraded a large code base from VB 2008 to 2013 and some unwanted behavior is resulting.  As a VB novice, I am having a hard time identifying the source and solution to one of these behaviors.

When my main form is either moved or reactivated (as a result of a subsequent form being closed), it shrinks to the smallest possible size and relocates to the very top-left of the screen.

There are no events on this form that have anything to do with resizing or restoring.  I have also tried to set up code breaks at strategic points to trap the code that is causing this behavior, but to no avail.

I would appreciate your help.  Thanks.

Comment: I'd really like to help but it's gonna be hard since I don't have any code. Is it a really big project or is there a chance that you could upload it somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered my own question and am posting the answer here in case anyone else ever does something silly (like I did)...

During the upgrade process, in a well-intentioned attempt to suppress some errors, I commented out the following code in the Settings.Designer.vb module...

```
    <Global.System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute(),  _
     Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(),  _
     Global.System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("0, 0")>  _
    Public Property MainFormLocation() As Global.System.Drawing.Point
        Get
            Return CType(Me("MainFormLocation"), Global.System.Drawing.Point)
        End Get
        Set
            Me("MainFormLocation") = Value
        End Set
    End Property
```

Simply uncommenting-out this code solved the problem.